# counter avoid repeat with using multithread requests

Tags: php, mysql

Im making a script that get data of a mysql MyISAM table each time that this script is requested/running.
the query is something like this:

SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, 10;

The problem is that the $offset must be 0 in the first request and 10 in second, 20 in third etc etc.
Then I created a new table where I have a counter for $offset that increment +10 each time that script
is requested.

You will must know that the script will have many request at same time. the request are not users (visits)
the request are my software running in more than 5 PC and each one of these software running with
more than 1000 threads doing requests to this script. Then Im searching a solution for not return
to these threads the same results if 2 or more threads will request to this script exactly at same time.
Also I need that counter will increment perfect.

```
function GetAndUpdateCounter($numberToAdd)
{
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','abcd1234');
    if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('dbcounter',$link);

        // in the 2 lines below I have my question about what happend if 2 or
        // more threads/request do this at same time, will get same result and will do same update
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM counter");
    mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET id=(id+$numberToAdd);");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    mysql_close($link);
    return $row['id'];
}
```

example calling the function

```
$offset = GetAndUpdateCounter(10);
```

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, 10");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before listing the solutions to your problem, I would like to give you a piece of advice: **Don't, please, don't use mysql_ functions, they are potentially harmful and deprecated in the newest PHP version.**

There are several ways you can achieve what you want. I would list them in an ascending order by priority.

1. *Manual MySQL table locks.* You can lock a table, select + update your desired value, then unlock the table again. The reason I chose it first in the priority list is, it has a good internal locking system that has high efficiency. Prototype, taken from MySQL's manual pages:

   ```
   LOCK TABLES trans READ, customer WRITE;
   SELECT SUM(value) FROM trans WHERE customer_id=some_id;
   UPDATE customer
      SET total_value=sum_from_previous_statement
      WHERE customer_id=some_id;
   UNLOCK TABLES;
   ```
2. *Using the same locking principle in your scripting language(PHP)*. You can either [flock](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.flock.php) the whole process of selecting and updating the field with creating an empty file for the locking purpose only, or you can use Memcached to set, check if the process is busy, and release when the process is finished. Those approaches are **not recommended**, since one of the processes could always crash while being in a "busy" mode, thus blocking the other processes until Memcached is released.